# Why does the request for resources return a 404 error after deploying a Vue.js project?

Tags: vue.js, deployment, http-status-code-404, single-page-application, web-frontend

I initially accessed the website without any issues, but after updating and deploying it, I encountered the following error when refreshing the site. It displayed 'from disk (404 not found).' The solution was to enable Chrome's 'disable cache' feature, and upon refreshing again, the status code changed from 404 to 200.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOVbK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUDqx.png)

What could be the possible reason for this? How can one ensure that a 404 error doesn't occur, and instead, a correct 200 response is received without enabling 'disable cache'?

I searched some questions about 'Vue 404'.
However, I couldn't find an answer to the related question, and I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Your web server should include a header telling the client not to cache index.js.  The exact solution will depend on your hosting framework.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/6225326) for more information